# Docker Container npm ERR! Internal watch failed: Circular symlink detected

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have created an express API and it would run normally on port 5000. When I put it on Docker container, it run at first but then I get an error message like this.

```
> nodejs-express-sequelize-postgresql@1.0.0 start
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:33) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:33) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Sequelize' of module exports inside circular dependency
Server is running on port 5000.
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "simplenims" ("id"   SERIAL , "nim" VARCHAR(255), "nama" VARCHAR(255), "status" BOOLEAN, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: Circular symlink detected: "/usr/bin/X11" points to "/usr/bin"
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c nodemon server.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-14T11_53_26_130Z-debug.log
```

This is my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY package*.json ./
 
RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV port=5000

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I followed Docker's documentation to make the Dockerfile. Is there something wrong or I need to add with the Dockcerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon watches all files inside the project root directory. To avoid this problem, you can create `nodemon.js` file in project root with the following content:

```
{
  "ext": "js"
}
```

This answer is from Github issue. It is really similar to your problem.

[**[Github Issue]** Internal watch failed: Circular symlink detected](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1786)

[**[Original Answer]**](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1786#issuecomment-722502923)

Answer (score -1):

This is related to nodemon. Here's how to solve -

With dockerfile like so:

```
 FROM node:14.15.0
 WORKDIR /app 
 COPY . /app 
 RUN npm install 
 CMD npm run dev
```

Build the image and then run it in a container with interactive terminal (optional), mounting a volume from the current host directory (pwd) to the WORKDIR (/app) in the container:

```sh
docker build -t imagename:tag .
docker run -it -p 1234:1234 -v $(pwd):/app imagename:tag
```

Or, with docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  server:
    build: .
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

Then run

```sh
docker-compose up --build
```